# WPF carousel / rotating elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, carousel

I am developing a software which takes automated photos using a camera. I want the user to be able to set the photo interval. I would like that to look and work like some kind of carousel.

This is what it should look like:
[image]

when I swipe (or drag with the mouse) it should move in the given direction:
[image]

the selected item should always be in the middle and if it's the last one, the first should rotate to the right (or vice versa).

I have already added the basic swipe/drag functionality, it recognizes whenever an action has been taken and in which direction. Hovewer, I have no idea on how to actually move the items.

Currently, the items are defined like this:

```xaml
<StackPanel x:Name="countdownContainer" Background="{StaticResource GuiSideBarBackgroundColor}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CountdownElement}" Text="3s"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CountdownElementSelected}" Text="5s"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CountdownElement}" Text="10s"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I know some basics about animation, but I don't know how to animate them like I need here.
Would it be better to use some other controls instead of a StackPanel and TextBlock elements?

Comment: You checked out any of the [existing carousel](http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/) controls available out there yet? Might save you some trouble.

Comment: Yes, I already checked that one out. I'd like to create it myself though since I'd like to learn something in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I base myself on the styles you have declared above, but not included in the code. You can do this in pure xaml and a viewmodel. This will be a very simple and crude example. Alternativly you could implement  a custom control that inherhits a class that has the **[Selector class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.110).aspx)** somewhere down the hierarchy, rather than control which is the default provided by the default cust control template in vs. I reccomend you to have a look at the MVVM pattern and Galasoft MVVM Light. In this example I've exluded **[touch gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010(v=vs.110).aspx)**, they are easy to imlplement and using EventToCommand you can use them directly in your vm or custcontrol*.

**Resources**

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="YourItemsPanelTemplate">
   <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="YourDataTemplate">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CountdownElement}" Text="{Binding .}" x:Name="PART_TextBlock"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"> 
            <!-- Here I'm just changing your fontsize, do whatever you want here :) -->                                       
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="34" TargetName="PART_TextBlock"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="YourContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource YourDataTemplate}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="YourListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource YourContainerStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource YourDataTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource YourItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

There is your styles, now for the xaml code, note that I bind your items here, and are using the styles described above.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Background="{StaticResource  GuiSideBarBackgroundColor}" 
        Style="{StaticResource YourListBoxStyle}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CountDownElements}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Grid>
```

**The ViewModel**
Remeber to set this as datacontext for your view, or copy the code to your codebehind.

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> countDownElements = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1s", "2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "10s" };
    private string selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<string> CountDownElements
    {
        get { return countDownElements; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, countDownElements)) return;
            countDownElements = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value == selectedItem) return;
            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // remove if you don't have R#
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Very simple stuff]

Hope it helps or at least kicks you in the right direction! :)

Cheers

Stian

Comment: Thank you Stian :) I actually thought about using a ListView, didn't try it though since there is another question I am facing: how to make the ListView infinite (or looping). What I would like to achieve is to have the selected item always shown in the center, and the other elements around it, looping. As shown in my two images, where "3s" moves to the right when selecting "10s".
Would I need to just reorder the elements in the collection and redrawing the ListView each time, or is there a better approach for that?

Comment: @DavideDeSantis for that you might have to create your own itemspanel, I did my Bachelor Thesis coding on the first Microsoft Surface(The big table). Actually almost identical to your problem, but I can't share this code, as it belongs to the company I did the thesis for. Basicly you create a panel and set ItemsHost=true on your panel in the control template. [This example is outdated, as Dr.WPF stopped coding WPF in 2010](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/panels/), yet it may point you in the right direction. You will need to impleent the IScrollInfo interface.

Comment: @DavideDeSantis np! It's a bit funny as this was actually one of my key controls on the thesis, didn't remember/realize it before later on after my inital answer :) I was learnin C# and WPF at that time. You will most likely bang your head against the wall on occations, but at least today touch is mainstream, and a part of ordinary windows and WPF.